# How can I prevent a border on a TTThumbView in Three20

Tags: three20

I'm using TTThumbView to show images but before the image is loaded I can see a border on the TTThumbView and then once the image is loaded I believe I'm getting a border showing through the edge of my image. Can anyone point me in the direction to prevent this please - I'm not sure if it's something I should set in styleForState.
I have tried the Three20 forum but have not had any responses yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your stylesheets `thumbView:` implementation. You would want to remove the TTSolidBorderStyle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I really want to try it out but the three20 site is down at the moment so I can't get any details of setting up a stylesheet - do you have a link to a resource please with recent docs covering that please?

Comment: You need a subclass of `TTDefaultStylesheet`, in which you overwrite the `thumbView:` implementation. You'll then set this as a the global stylesheet in you `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`implementation via `[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[MYStyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];`

Comment: Thanks @tonklon - that was a great explanation and worked perfectly